# Why do I get an authentication error when trying to join docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I am trying to run

```
docker-machine ssh myvm2 "docker swarm join --token SwMTKN-1-<cut> 192.168.161.163:2376"
```

to join mymv2 as a worker to the cluster, but I get this error

> Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all Subconns are in TransientFailure,
>   latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: remote error: tls: bad certificate" exit status 1

I am following the docker course at :https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/get-started/part4/#create-a-cluster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the port to 2377 in --advertise-addr while creating swarm and join the other managers and workers using the same port to solve this problem.